# Is it possible to pass an array of functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass functions in an array to a component in React. Whole code is below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Parse from 'parse/dist/parse.min.js';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import EntryHeader from '../Components/common/entryHeader/EntryHeader';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { Typography, Link, Container, Button } from '@mui/material';
import EntryPageInput from '../Components/EntryPageInput';
import ConfirmationBox from '../Components/ConfirmationBox';
const Signup = () => {
    let history = useNavigate();
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [password2, setPassword2] = useState('');
    const [isequal, setIsequal] = useState(false);
    const [openBox, setOpenBox] = useState(false);
    const notAccept = async function () {
        setOpenBox(false);
    }
    const doUserRegistration = async function () {
        const usernameValue = username;
        const passwordValue = password;
        const passwordValue2 = password2;
        if (passwordValue === passwordValue2) {
            try {
                const createdUser = await Parse.User.signUp(usernameValue, passwordValue);
                alert(
                    `Success! User ${createdUser.getUsername()} was successfully created!`
                );
                //const currentUser = await Parse.User.current();
                createdUser.set("level", "admin");
                await createdUser.save();
                setOpenBox(false);
                history("/addCompanyInfo");
                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                setOpenBox(false);
                alert(`Error! ${error}`);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('password is not matching!');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    };
    useEffect(()=>{
        (password === password2 && password !== "") ? setIsequal(true) : setIsequal(false);
    }, [password2]);

    return (
        <Container
            maxWidth={false}
            sx={{
                marginTop: '100px',
                maxWidth: '400px'
            }}>
            <Box sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'center',
                rowGap: 2,
            }}>
                <EntryHeader />
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5"> Kullanıcı Kayıt </Typography>
                <Box sx={{ width: '400px' }}>
                    <EntryPageInput label='Username' onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)} />
                    <EntryPageInput label='Password' onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)} type='password' />
                    <EntryPageInput label='Re-type password' onChange={(event) => setPassword2(event.target.value)} color = {isequal ? "success" : "warning"} helperText = {isequal ? "matching" : "not matching"} type='password' />
                </Box>
                <Button
                    variant='contained'
                    onClick={() => setOpenBox(true)}
                    sx={{
                        width: '200px'
                    }}
                >
                    Sign Up
                </Button>
                {/* <SocialLogin></SocialLogin> */}
                <Typography component="h6" variant="h6">Already have an account?<Link href="/login">Log in</Link> </Typography>
                <ConfirmationBox  
                    funcList=[doUserRegistration(),notAccept()]
                    //accept={() => doUserRegistration()} notAccept={() => notAccept()} openBox={openBox} 
                    title={"Kayıt olmak istediğine emin misin ?"} 
                    context={"Kabul etmen durumunda deneme sürümü ve paketler konusunda sizinle iletişime geçeceğiz."}
                />
            </Box>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default Signup;
```

In the code above, we want to pass `doUserRegistration` and `notAccept` functions in array such that `funcList=[doUserRegistration(),notAccept()]` to component `ConfirmationBox`. I tried like `funcList=[doUserRegistration(),notAccept()]`. It doesn't work. I couldn't find such example. Is it possible, and if it is, how? I also add specific part of code below.

Functions:

```
 const notAccept = async function () {
        setOpenBox(false);
    }
    const doUserRegistration = async function () {
        const usernameValue = username;
        const passwordValue = password;
        const passwordValue2 = password2;
        if (passwordValue === passwordValue2) {
            try {
                const createdUser = await Parse.User.signUp(usernameValue, passwordValue);
                alert(
                    `Success! User ${createdUser.getUsername()} was successfully created!`
                );
                //const currentUser = await Parse.User.current();
                createdUser.set("level", "admin");
                await createdUser.save();
                setOpenBox(false);
                history("/addCompanyInfo");
                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                setOpenBox(false);
                alert(`Error! ${error}`);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('password is not matching!');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    };
```

Component that we want to pass array :

```
 <ConfirmationBox  
                    funcList=[doUserRegistration(),notAccept()]
                    //accept={() => doUserRegistration()} notAccept={() => notAccept()} openBox={openBox} 
                    title={"Kayıt olmak istediğine emin misin ?"} 
                    context={"Kabul etmen durumunda deneme sürümü ve paketler konusunda sizinle iletişime geçeceğiz."}
                />
```

Comment: `funcList={[doUserRegistration,notAccept]}`. You don't want to call the functions, which is what `()` does.

Comment: You can do it with `funcList={[doUserRegistration,notAccept]}`, but I've got to ask... Why? This seems like a step backwards in every way

Comment: Of course you can pass an array, but you have to: 1. use valid syntax to interpolate a value: `funcList={[/* content */]}`; and 2. not _call_ the functions first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I want to add these functions to unknown number of component like button. I dont know exactly the  for example number of buttons and functions in every time when I call ConfirmationBox component. I want it to be reusable. I add these functions to attr onClick according to their index.

Comment: So it's possible but not ideal. It's better to name your methods when passing as props. That way each function call be called without having to access by index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the functions and passing them, that will pass the results of that function which is not what you want. Pass the functions instead

```
<ConfirmationBox  
                    funcList={[doUserRegistration,notAccept]}
                    //accept={() => doUserRegistration()} notAccept={() => notAccept()} openBox={openBox} 
                    title={"Kayıt olmak istediğine emin misin ?"} 
                    context={"Kabul etmen durumunda deneme sürümü ve paketler konusunda sizinle iletişime geçeceğiz."}
                />
```